# Regarding Chapter 11 of Eloquent Javascript 3rd Edition

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm reading through Chapter 11 of Eloquent Javascript 3rd Edition (link: https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html) and I'm having a hard time getting the following line of code to work:

```js
routeRequest(bigOak, "Church Tower", "note", "Incoming jackdaws!");
```

The code works in the interactive sandbox, but if I try to run that line of code myself (saved the files https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/chapter/11_async.js & https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/crow-tech.js in a local directory, added the above code snippet to the 11_async.js file and ran "node 11_async.js") it returns an error, "Error: No route to Church Tower". The only way it will work is if i run with some setTimeout:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  routeRequest(bigOak, "Church Tower", "note", "Incoming jackdaws!");
}, 3000)
```

This makes sense to me because it takes some time to propagate all the connections, but the chapter/author doesn't describe the need to run with a setTimeout/delay and I am wondering if I'm missing something...

Appreciate any help...

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The error is "Error: No route to Church Tower", whereas with the setTimeout i get a successful "Church Tower received note: Incoming jackdaws!" message...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information and code. Links to off-site services are fine as supplementary information but everything required to understand your question should be here. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (with particular focus on the **minimal**)

Comment: I'v just come across the same problem running the code on my environment. With delay times somewhere below 1000ms the error occurs again.

Answer (score 0):

The Eloquent also has a sandbox. Please check the file "crow-tech.js". This has  code that specifically waits for 500ms so that routeRequest, findInStorage, and chicks work only after the network information has propagated.

```js
if (typeof __sandbox != "undefined") {
    __sandbox.handleDeps = false
    __sandbox.notify.onLoad = () => {
      // Kludge to make sure some functions are delayed until the
      // nodes have been running for 500ms, to give them a chance to
      // propagate network information.
      let waitFor = Date.now() + 500
      function wrapWaiting(f) {
        return function(...args) {
          let wait = waitFor - Date.now()
          if (wait <= 0) return f(...args)
          return new Promise(ok => setTimeout(ok, wait)).then(() => f(...args))
        }
      }
      for (let n of ["routeRequest", "findInStorage", "chicks"])
        window[n] = wrapWaiting(window[n])
    }
  }
```